# unix timestamp format converter in iphone

Tags: iphone

im using json in my new app. im getting time in UNIX timestamps format. i try to get this done by this code..

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1234567];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
int weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
```

this work correctly if i try to passed time hardcoaded but didn't work on dynamically. means i didnot get in which format(decimalnumber, double) should i passed a variable in place of 1234567?

please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `+dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:`, you will see that it takes an [NSTimeInterval](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html), which is simply a double.